# How to get values of mysql database based on textbox values given in another form

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried it using `C#` and `MySQL`

```
MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "select student_name,student_reg_no  FROM student WHERE student_id ='" + form2.textBox1.Text + "';";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
               label1.Text = myReader[0].ToString();
               label2.Text = myReader[1].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        conn.Close();
```

not showing the record in the labels and no error message.

Comment: Maybe you can use a breakpoint and check the constructed command text is correct or not?

Comment: Have you debugged the while loop, does reader iterate over any records?

Comment: can you debug form2.textBox1.Text value and check in student  column  id is present or not